# How can I create a Dynamic button, within WooCommerce, to take people to the Product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in the process of creating a WordPress Theme, with WooCommerce functionality.

For the Homepage, I have inserted the WooCommerce Shortcode: `[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4"]` in order to pull the latest Products.  This Shortcode generates a 'Button' which, when selected, adds the Product Item to the basket.  I want to remove this and replace it with a standard button which directs people to the Product Page, in order to read more about the product.  To achieve this, I have entered the following code into the function.php file:

```
//Removes Default 'Add to Basket Button':
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );

//More Info Button
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_more_info' );

function woocommerce_more_info() {
    echo '<a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">More Info</a>';  
}
```

My problem lies in that whilst the Link Text appears in the correct position, the link does not work.  Rather than taking me to the concerned Product, takes me to the following link:

http://www.example.com/%3C?php%20the_permalink();%20?%3E

Could somebody let me know what changes I would need to perform, in order for the link to take me to the Product please.

Also, how could I go about styling such a button?  Would I include the  in this function or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `echo` correctly.

This line:

```
echo '<a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">More Info</a>';
```

Should be:

```
echo '<a id="id-'. get_the_id() .'" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">More Info</a>';
```

The difference between [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) and [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) is that the first displays the content immediately, whereas the latter returns the value, so you can use it in a string. The same goes for the other functions you've used.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for this answer.  Worked perfectly!